# TTY1 on Video Projector

Tags: display, tty, projector

Is it somehow possible to display TTY1 or similar to a video projector? `xrandr` cannot open the display:

```
$ xrandr --query
Can't open display
```

I have a ATI graphics card and am not using the proprietary drivers.
Booting with the projector attached changes nothing. I don't see output in the BIOS, in the GRUB menu as well as when booting Ubuntu (graphical as well as text based). I get an image when the login screen shows up.

Answer (score 1):

X-randr only controls the X-Server, i.e. your graphical desktop. That's why xrandr cannot open the display on tty1 .. there is none.

Not using the proprietary drivers is generally a good thing (imho.) Have you tried rebooting with the projector attached? Do you see the Part of the Bootloader, kernel output whatever. You will probably have an image up to some certain point. Or maybe this does the trick entirely.

Post your results. ;-)